# Add a button in a Table in focframework

Tags: java

I am using [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-framework) as full stack to develop a web application in JAVA.

I want to add a column to my table and in that column I want to place a Button. It could also be any other component but for the moment I want to place a button. For example like the ones in red we see bellow:

[image]

I only know how to add columns to show the properties of the FocObject displayed in the Table. And This is easy in the Form's XML like bellow:

```
<GuiTable title="Employees" name="EMPLOYEE_GUI_TABLE" dataPath="DATAROOT" >
    <TableColumn name="_LINE_NUMBER" />
    <TableColumn name="FirstName" caption="FirstName" link="true"/>
    <TableColumn name="LastName" caption="LastName" link="true"/>
    <TableColumn name="StartShift" caption="StartShift" />
    <TableColumn name="EndShift" caption="EndShift" />
</GuiTable>
```

I want to add a new Column but the content is not a property of the FocObject. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In focframework, To add a custom column that does not show a FocObject property you start by adding it with a name of your choice in the Form.xml like bellow:

```
<GuiTable title="Employees" name="EMPLOYEE_GUI_TABLE" dataPath="DATAROOT" >
    <TableColumn name="_LINE_NUMBER" />
    ...
    <TableColumn name="EndShift" caption="EndShift" />
    <TableColumn name="PRINT_BUTTON" caption="Print" />
</GuiTable>
```

Note the PRINT_BUTTON is the name I chose for my column.

Now in your Form java class you need to override the following method **table_getGeneratedColumn** which should return null if you want to let FOC manage the component creating but in our case and for that particular column name PRINT_BUTTON we want to return a special generator:

```
public ColumnGenerator table_getGeneratedColumn(String tableName, final FVTableColumn tableColumn) {
    ColumnGenerator columnGenerator = null;
    if (    tableColumn != null 
            &&  tableColumn.getName() != null
            &&  tableColumn.getName().equals("PRINT_BUTTON")) {

        columnGenerator = new ColumnGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
                Button button = new Button("Print");
                button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        Globals.showNotification("Button Clicked", "The print button has been licked", IFocEnvironment.TYPE_HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
                    }
                });
                return button;
            }
        };

    }           
    return columnGenerator;
}
```

The result is the bellow:
[image]